# Block in sync method on background queue is executed on main thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Just started to learning about GCD and I am running into trouble because my code is still ran on the main thread while I created a background queue. This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "internalqueue", qos: .background)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dispatchFun {
            assert(Thread.isMainThread)

            let x = UIView()
        }
    }

    func dispatchFun(handler: @escaping (() -> ())) {
        queue.sync {
            handler()
        }
    }
}
```

Surprising enough (for me), is that this code doesn't throw any error! I would expect the assertion would fail. I would expect the code is not ran on the main thread. In the debugger I see that when constructing the `x` instance, that I am in my queue on thread 1 (by seeing the label). Strange, because normally I see the main thread label on thread 1. Is my queue scheduled on the main thread (thread 1)?

**When I change `sync` for `async`, the assertion fails**. This is what I would expect to happen with `sync` aswell. Below is an attached image of the threads when the assertion failed. **I would expect to see the exact same debug information when I use `sync` instead of `async`.**

[image]

When reading the `sync` description in the Swift source, I read the following:

```
/// As an optimization, `sync(execute:)` invokes the work item on the thread which
/// submitted it, except when the queue is the main queue or
/// a queue targetting it.
```

Again: **except when the queue is the main queue**

Why does the `sync` method on a background dispatch queue cases the code to run on the main thread, but `async` doesn't? I can clearly read that the sync method on a queue shouldn't be ran on the main thread, but why does my code ignore that scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you’re misreading that comment in the header. It’s not a question of whether you’re dispatching *from* the `main` queue, but rather if you’re dispatching *to* the `main` queue.

So, here is the well known `sync` optimization where the dispatched block will run on the current thread:

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "internalqueue", attributes: .concurrent)

// We'll dispatch from main thread _to_ background queue

func dispatchingToBackgroundQueue() {
    backgroundQueue.sync {
        print(#function, "this sync will run on the current thread, namely the main thread; isMainThread =", Thread.isMainThread)
    }
    backgroundQueue.async {
        print(#function, "but this async will run on the background queue's thread; isMainThread =", Thread.isMainThread)
    }
}
```

When you use `sync`, you’re telling GCD “hey, have this thread wait until the other thread runs this block of code”. So, GCD is smart enough to figure out “well, if this thread is going to not do anything while I’m waiting for the block of code to run, I might as well run it here if I can, and save the costly context switch to another thread.”

But in the following scenario, we’re doing something on some background queue and want to dispatch it back to the `main` queue. In this case, GCD will not do the aforementioned optimization, but rather will always run the task dispatched to the `main` queue on the `main` queue:

```
// but this time, we'll dispatch from background queue _to_ the main queue

func dispatchingToTheMainQueue() {
    backgroundQueue.async {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            print(#function, "even though it’s sync, this will still run on the main thread; isMainThread =", Thread.isMainThread)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(#function, "needless to say, this async will run on the main thread; isMainThread =", Thread.isMainThread)
        }
    }
}
```

It does this because there are certain things that must run on the main queue (such as UI updates), and if you’re dispatching it to the main queue, it will always honor that request, and not try to do any optimization to avoid context switches.

---

Let’s consider a more practical example of the latter scenario.

```
func performRequest(_ url: URL) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            // we're guaranteed that this actually will run on the main thread
            // even though we used `sync`
        }
    }
}
```

Now, generally we’d use `async` when dispatching back to the main queue, but the comment in the `sync` header documentation is just letting us know that this task dispatched back to the main queue using `sync` will actually run on the main queue, not on `URLSession`’s background queue as you might otherwise fear.

Comment: Ah ok, so it is guaranteed that calling `sync` on a queue which is the main thread or targetting the main thread, will run on the main thread while other queue's do not have this privilege. That is indeed an important difference. However, I don't quite why GCD decides to run the `sync` on the main thread. I just want to do serial execution of blocks. A block in the queue should be only executed if all the previous added blocks of code are done. What is the use case of `sync`? It just looks like a regular method to me. Should `sync` be called inside a async block, since async will  surely

Comment: I now see that `sync` is called every time on the main thread. I have to find a way to execute a `sync` block in a different thread, since now it just blocks the whole UI. But maybe I have to investigate GCD more :)

Comment: Yep, I tried to clarify my answer. Bottom line, yes, when you call `sync` from the main queue to some background queue, it will generally run it on the main queue. The question, which is unclear to me from your original question, is _why_ you’re trying to call `sync` from the main queue. You generally wouldn’t do that for anything time consuming (because we never want to block the main queue).

Comment: I was indeed afraid to ask a practical usecase of calling `sync`. What I want is pretty basic: calling blocks one after another. The blocks should wait for eachother and executed in the way they were added. Everything should be executed on a background thread. The blocks should not be executed at the same time. I think I can accomplish this by creating a dispatch queue like I did in my question, but call `async` rather than `sync`. Do you think this is a good starting point? The dispatch queue I created is serial, since I do not add the concurrent attribute.

Comment: Yep, no reason for the main queue to wait for all of those dispatched blocks to finish. Use `async` when queueing these up on that background queue.

Comment: @JDoe - If you’re looking for practical example of `sync`, consider some object you plan on accessing from multiple threads: You might use `sync` with some dedicated synchronization queue to provide fast, thread-safe interaction to that object, but also confident that it won’t ever block long enough to be a problem.

Comment: A yes! I have seen indeed `sync` blocks in an object with a queue to omit race conditions! Everything makes a lot more sense now :)

Comment: It makes more sense to consider a background task (say an async block on a background queue) that needs to retrieve a value from the main thread before proceeding, say from a UI object. It could do that using a main.sync, retrieving the value. This does not block the main thread, but rather blocks the background thread, which is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Let's consider:

```
/// As an optimization, `sync(execute:)` invokes the work item on the thread which
/// submitted it, except when the queue is the main queue or
/// a queue targetting it.
```

You're invoking `sync()` on your own queue. Is that queue the main queue or targeting the main queue? No, it's not. So, the exception isn't relevant and only this part is:

> `sync(execute:)` invokes the work item on the thread which submitted it

So, the fact that your `queue` is a background queue doesn't matter. The block is executed by the thread where `sync()` was called, which is the main thread (which called `viewDidLoad()`, which called `dispatchFun()`).